# How do I reference a field in an ExpandoObject dynamically?

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

Is there a way to dynamically access the property of an expando using a "IDictionary" style lookup?

```
var messageLocation = "Message";
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Message = "I am awesome!";
Console.WriteLine(expando[messageLocation]);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to cast the `ExpandoObject` to `IDictionary<string, object>` :

```
var messageLocation = "Message";
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Message = "I am awesome!";

var expandoDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
Console.WriteLine(expandoDict[messageLocation]);
```

(Also your expando variable must be typed as `dynamic` so property access is determined at runtime - otherwise your sample won't compile)

Comment: Note that the conversion can be done implicitly: `IDictionary<string, object> expandoDict = expando;` will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I really really wish i could just say expando["whatever"] though. I don't really understand why the cast is necessary especially since it is dynamic.